# Making 5 images align within 3 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap.

I have a container
then a row.
The row has a list of images in a col-md-3.
The row has a list of articles within a col-md-9.

If the images move to the top of the screen (because the screen is small) I want them to be displayed horizontally in as many rows as necessary. When the images are on the left side of the screen, I want them to align vertically.

How do I do this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="https://www.coca-cola.com.au/bundles/cokeweb/uikit/img/logos/coke/logo-small-retina.png" width="170" height="50" border="0" alt="Coke">
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Mcdonalds-90s-logo.svg/2000px-Mcdonalds-90s-logo.svg.png" width="70" height="50" border="0" alt="Mcdonalds">
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Hershey_logo.svg/2000px-Hershey_logo.svg.png" width="180" height="50" border="0" alt="Hershey">
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c0/Frito_Lay_Logo.png/975px-Frito_Lay_Logo.png" width="70" height="50" border="0" alt="Frito Lay">
       <img src="https://jobdevelopers.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/levis-logo1.png" width="90" height="50" border="0" alt="Levis">
       <img src="http://www.shoutbusiness.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Decker-logo.jpg" width="100" height="50" border="0" alt="Black and Decker">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <p>python prints alot of articles here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT 1**

I am trying to make a jsfiddle of it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ced41zLy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create row with the column and set your break points:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.coca-cola.com.au/bundles/cokeweb/uikit/img/logos/coke/logo-small-retina.png" alt="Coke">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Mcdonalds-90s-logo.svg/2000px-Mcdonalds-90s-logo.svg.png" alt="Mcdonalds">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Hershey_logo.svg/2000px-Hershey_logo.svg.png" alt="Hershey">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c0/Frito_Lay_Logo.png/975px-Frito_Lay_Logo.png" alt="Frito Lay">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://jobdevelopers.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/levis-logo1.png" alt="Levis">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shoutbusiness.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Decker-logo.jpg" alt="Black and Decker">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
      <p>python prints alot of articles here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You can use Bootstrap's [.img-responsive](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp) so that you won't have to fuss with the width.